# Meu form esta carregando a pagina como parar isso?

Tags: javascript

Eu queria parar esse form de atualizar e tambem se possivel pegar os dados desse forma para uma var alguem me ajuda haha

```js
function pegarinformacoes() {
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value
    var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value
    var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value    
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <h2 id="titulo-form">Adicionar novo paciente</h2>
    <form>
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
            <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="digite o nome do seu paciente" class="campo">
        </div>
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="peso">Peso:</label>
            <input id="peso"  type="text" placeholder="digite o peso do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
        </div>
        <div class="grupo">
            <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
            <input id="altura"  type="text" placeholder="digite a altura do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
        </div>
        <button id="adicionar-paciente"  onClick="pegarinformacoes()" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: *"Meu form esta carregando a pagina como parar isso?"* não entendi o que isso quer dizer, sua pergunta está confusa, tente explicar melhor

Answer (score 1):

o método preventDefault() resolve isso. Tente assim:

1. Remova o vento onclick do botão ***adicionar-paciente***;
2. No arquivo javascript inclua a seguinte instrução no evento click do botão:

```js
document.getElementById('adicionar-paciente').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  pegarinformacoes();
}, false);

function pegarinformacoes() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value
  var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value
  var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value

  console.log(nome + ' - ' + altura + ' - ' + peso);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container">
    <h2 id="titulo-form">Adicionar novo paciente</h2>
    <form>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="digite o nome do seu paciente" class="campo">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="peso">Peso:</label>
        <input id="peso" type="text" placeholder="digite o peso do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
        <input id="altura" type="text" placeholder="digite a altura do seu paciente" class="campo campo-medio">
      </div>
      <button id="adicionar-paciente" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Dessa forma, ao clicar no botão o método preventDefault é acionado, prevenindo o carregamento da página e chama a função ***pegarInformações*** logo em seguida.

Teste e confirme.

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault